# get_or_create fails for unique_together for decimals

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class LocationPoint(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('latitude', 'longitude',),
        )
```

Interactor:

```
class GetOrCreateLocationPoint(object):

    def exec(self, latitude: Decimal, longitude: Decimal) -> LocationPoint:
        point, _ = LocationPoint.objects.get_or_create(
            latitude=latitude,
            longitude=longitude,

            defaults={
                'latitude': latitude,
                'longitude': longitude,
            },
        )

        return point
```

And test:

```
class GetOrCreateLocationPointTest(TestCase): # from django.test import TestCase
    __get_or_create_location_point: GetOrCreateLocationPoint

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.__get_or_create_location_point = GetOrCreateLocationPoint()

    def test_create_duplicate(self):
        point1 = self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal(10.5), Decimal(5.01))
        self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal(13.4), Decimal(1.5343))
        point3 = self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal(10.5), Decimal(5.01))

        self.assertEqual(point1.pk, point3.pk)
```

I get an error while executing `point3 = self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal(10.5), Decimal(5.01))`:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "geo_locationpoint_latitude_longitude_08fb2a82_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (latitude, longitude)=(10.500000, 5.010000) already exists.
```

However, if in debugger I see that `self.model.DoesNotExist` is thrown (and handled) in `get_or_create`, so it does not find the existing row.

What's wrong?

Django 3.0.3, PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is `get_or_create` throwing the `IntegrityError` or `DoesNotExist`?

Comment: @AustinPhilp it handles `DoesNotExist` internally (see get_or_create implementation), tries to create new row and then raises `IntegrityError`

Comment: gotcha, well I'm not sure if this will resolve your issue or not, but you actually don't need to provide latitude and longitude as your defaults. Since they're already lookup params, they'll be included in the new object. The relevant section of the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) provides a helpful "equivalent code" sample, which illustrates how each param is used

Comment: @AustinPhilp you're right, `defaults` is redundant, however, it did not affect the issue :(

Comment: that's a shame, I'm near a machine with Django right now, but if no one has helped you when I get home tonight, I'll try to play around a bit and see if I can figure anything out. Best of luck!

Comment: @AustinPhilp lol, just fixed it, the issue was in floats, take a look at my answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems to fail because of using floats in `Decimal` constructors…

Replacing floats with string representation resolved the issue:

```
    def test_create_duplicate(self):
        point1 = self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal('10.5'), Decimal('5.01'))
        self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal('13.4'), Decimal('1.5343'))
        point3 = self.__get_or_create_location_point.exec(Decimal('10.5'), Decimal('5.01'))

        self.assertEqual(point1.pk, point3.pk)
```